# Concatenate two NumPy arrays vertically

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, concatenation

I tried the following:

```
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3])
>>> b = np.array([4,5,6])
>>> np.concatenate((a,b), axis=0)
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
>>> np.concatenate((a,b), axis=1)
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

However, I'd expect at least that one result looks like this

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

Why is it not concatenated vertically?

Comment: weird !!! You can use `np.vstack((a,b))` for this purpose (in case you don't know it)

Comment: Guys, sorry for the stupid comment, but why do you use brackets twice in case of vstack?

Comment: @DmitryIsakov Don't worry, it's not a stupid comment. numpy does this because the one required argument when using `vstack` is a tuple. In other words, `np.vstack((a,b))` is the same as doing `np.vstack(tup=(a,b))`. See here: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html

Comment: @DmitryIsakov assuming of course that you were asking about parentheses `( )` and not square brackets `[ ]`

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Because both `a` and `b` have only one axis, as their shape is `(3)`, and the axis parameter specifically refers to the axis of the elements to concatenate.

this example should clarify what `concatenate` is doing with axis. Take two vectors with two axis, with shape `(2,3)`:

```
a = np.array([[1,5,9], [2,6,10]])
b = np.array([[3,7,11], [4,8,12]])
```

concatenates along the 1st axis (rows of the 1st, then rows of the 2nd):

```
np.concatenate((a,b), axis=0)
array([[ 1,  5,  9],
       [ 2,  6, 10],
       [ 3,  7, 11],
       [ 4,  8, 12]])
```

concatenates along the 2nd axis (columns of the 1st, then columns of the 2nd):

```
np.concatenate((a, b), axis=1)
array([[ 1,  5,  9,  3,  7, 11],
       [ 2,  6, 10,  4,  8, 12]])
```

to obtain the output you presented, you can use `vstack`

```
a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = np.array([4,5,6])
np.vstack((a, b))
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

You can still do it with `concatenate`, but you need to reshape them first:

```
np.concatenate((a.reshape(1,3), b.reshape(1,3)))
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

Finally, as proposed in the comments, one way to reshape them is to use `newaxis`:

```
np.concatenate((a[np.newaxis,:], b[np.newaxis,:]))
```

Comment: are you sure reshaping will work? It didn't work for me.

Comment: Try `np.concatenate([a[None,:],b[None,:]])`

Comment: yes it does. Maybe you ran `a.reshape(1,3)` without assigning it, instead of `a=a.reshape(1,3)`?

Comment: strange. I suppose you then did `d=b.reshape(1,3)`? Still, `concatenate((c,d))` works here.

Comment: Actually this implementation is not particularly intutive. At some (suprisingly basic) points numpy does not make sense to me.

Comment: So why doesn't Numpy raise an exception? It's clearly a contradiction in terms when we explicitly request `axis=1`, when it is non-existent.

Comment: `np.newaxis` is `None` (quite literally) and makes its intent clearer than `None` -- `a[np.newaxis, :]`.

Comment: Please edit the answer changing `vstack((a,b))` to `np.vstack((a,b))`

Answer (score 35):

If the actual problem at hand is to concatenate two 1-D arrays vertically, and we are not fixated on using `concatenate` to perform this operation, I would suggest the use of **[np.column_stack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html)**:

```
In []: a = np.array([1,2,3])
In []: b = np.array([4,5,6])
In []: np.column_stack((a, b))
array([[1, 4],
       [2, 5],
       [3, 6]])
```

Answer (score 11):

A not well known feature of numpy is to use `r_`. This is a simple way to build up arrays quickly:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = np.array([4,5,6])
c = np.r_[a[None,:],b[None,:]]
print(c)
#[[1 2 3]
# [4 5 6]]
```

The purpose of `a[None,:]` is to add an axis to array `a`.

Answer (score 6):

```
a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = np.array([4,5,6])
np.array((a,b))
```

works just as well as

```
np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
```

Regardless of whether it is a list of lists or a list of 1d arrays, `np.array` tries to create a 2d array.

But it's also a good idea to understand how `np.concatenate` and its family of `stack` functions work.  In this context `concatenate` needs a list of 2d arrays (or any anything that `np.array` will turn into a 2d array) as inputs.

`np.vstack` first loops though the inputs making sure they are at least 2d, then does concatenate.  Functionally it's the same as expanding the dimensions of the arrays yourself.

`np.stack` is a new function that joins the arrays on a new dimension.  Default behaves just like `np.array`.

Look at the code for these functions.  If written in Python you can learn quite a bit.  For `vstack`:

```
return _nx.concatenate([atleast_2d(_m) for _m in tup], 0)
```