# How can I vertically concatenate 1x2 arrays in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

How can I concatenate 1x2 arrays produced in another function?

I have a for loop that produces xa as output, which is a float64 (1L,2L).

```
xa = [[ 1.17281823  1.210732  ]]
```

The code I tried for concatenate is

```
A = []
for i in range(5): 
    # actually xa = UglyCalculation(**Inputs[i])
    xa = np.array([[ i, i+1 ]]) # for our example here
    # do something
```

All I want to do is concatenate/join/append these xa values vertically.

Basically the desired output should be

```
 0 1
 1 2
 2 3 
 3 4 
 4 5
```

I have tried the following lines of code, but it's not working. Can you help?

```
 A = np.concatenate((A, xa)) # Concatenate the matrices 
 A = np.concatenate((A,xa),axis=0)
 A=np.vstack((A,xa))
```

Comment: You can use `vstack` to do this.

Comment: @ebarr Added to the list of things I tried and failed. Error: ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly

Comment: Try `A = np.vstack([xb + K*(y[i] - hxb) for i in range(676)])`

Comment: you call also just use: `np.array([xb + K*(y[i] - hxb) for i in range(676)])`

Comment: Hi, I have added some more info. The code is pretty large. And I only gave one line of the for loop earlier. I understand the line you are giving me. But not sure how to use it....@ebarr @halex

Comment: I think if you simplified the question your chances are better to obtain a clear answer.  You probably don't need `K`, `y[i]` or `hxb` or `range(0,676,1)` to ask a question that yields a 5x2 matrix.  Especially when we don't know about these variables, and would probably prefer not to...

Comment: @maximusdooku At the end of your loop add the line `A.append(xa)` and after the loop do `A = np.vstack(A)`

Comment: True. All I want to do is the concatenate the xa 1*2 arrays...

Comment: @halex Thanks a lot. I used A.append(xa) and this is what I get: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: @maximusdooku I simplified your question.  If you disapprove, you can roll it back (or just say so).  This will allow for an answer useful to more people in the future.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21887754/numpy-concatenate-two-arrays-vertically

Comment: Note: They are concatenating arrays of same size. While in my case, the first is getting added to a blank array. Could that be an issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting a shape on A allows concatenation of similar column sized arrays:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([])
A.shape=(0,2) # set A to be 0 rows x 2 cols matrix
for i in range(5):
    xa = np.array([[i, i+1]])
    A = np.concatenate( (A,xa) )
print A

output
[[ 0.  1.]
 [ 1.  2.]
 [ 2.  3.]
 [ 3.  4.]
 [ 4.  5.]]
```

without `A.shape = (0,2)` an Exception will be thrown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./arr.py", line 5, in <module>
    A = np.concatenate( (A,xa) )
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

Comment: @maximusdooku Good luck with it.