# Python/Numpy joining subarrays of an array together

Tags: python, numpy

Currently I have a list of arrays as follows:

```
array =
[array([100000.        , 100848.06652142,  99648.67144694, 102047.67944271,
       103655.99048427, 104602.87678005, 104597.83419837, 103505.42736768,
       104976.01311214, 104457.34603404, 105855.46549162, 105613.30235519,
       105212.71840922, 107647.5054673 ])
 array([107647.5054673 , 106891.82007643, 106979.91405552, 106030.74186486,
       107856.04281712, 108502.71948581, 106557.2401056 , 105659.59829843,
       105663.01875745, 107300.69453018, 106336.34733019, 107584.99034227,
       108089.2320392 , 106786.91702337])
 array([106786.91702337, 104416.74000465, 101289.12525402, 101932.58219813,
       102625.04352578, 101767.46209616, 103345.4263012 , 102816.73322055,
       102417.59316407, 104439.37518975, 103755.22627215, 103817.9744686 ,
       107872.40234863, 108110.9662065 ])
 array([108110.9662065 , 109544.86827069, 111072.22392645, 112618.46235766,
       113847.1768898 , 116708.86391903, 115790.02599715, 115614.72242411,
       119225.88436354, 121991.38468934, 123304.85972848, 125571.38040251,
       122456.3667249 ])
 array([122456.3667249 , 127497.74699282, 128659.85495604, 125813.77115906,
       129008.46450085, 128111.00914756, 123039.92607546, 124723.87932757,
       124181.57385836, 125134.9276196 , 126027.8631434 , 129304.85119148,
       128912.58600657])]
```

What would be the best possible way to join all these subarrays back together into one large array? I tried `np.concatenate()` but that did not work.

**SOLUTION**

For whatever reason, my output would not put commas between the subarrays, once I was able to find the fix for that `np.concatenate()` did indeed work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [numpy concatenate two arrays vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21887754/numpy-concatenate-two-arrays-vertically)

Comment: Could you use smaller arrays in your examples, preferably with more humane values that are easy to track when checking the solution?

Comment: Also, how do you want to join the arrays? Vertically? Horizontally? That is why it helps to show desired output. Finally, even though `np.concatenate()` did not work for you, can you show the actual code that you have attempted.

Comment: Why do you also say that `np.concatenate()` **to no surprise** did not work? _I am_ surprised!

Comment: Another possible duplicate (depending on the question) is here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9236926/8033585

Comment: @AGNGazer I apologize, I misspoke, I meant to say to my surprise. And for whatever reason, my output was not putting commas in between the subarrays, and after finding the fix for that concatenate did work. I apologize for writing a rather stupid question

Comment: When a `print` display of an object omits commas, that means it's a numpy array, not a list.  Your `array` looks like an object dtype array of `ndarrays`.  I can make a valid list from @AGNGazer's modification.  But when I try `concatenate` I get the `shape shape` error message.  `np.array(thatlist, dtype=object)` produces an array whose 'print(arr)` looks like your `array`.  The `repr` adds an outer `array` and `object` dtype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
np.concatenate(array)
```

The only problem, in your example, `array` in the list `array` (now, do you see how bad it is to use confusing names) should become `np.array` and you should add commas after each `numpy.ndarray` in the list `array`:

```
array = [np.array([100000., 100848.06652142,  99648.67144694, 102047.67944271,
       103655.99048427, 104602.87678005, 104597.83419837, 103505.42736768,
       104976.01311214, 104457.34603404, 105855.46549162, 105613.30235519,
       105212.71840922, 107647.5054673 ]),
 np.array([107647.5054673 , 106891.82007643, 106979.91405552, 106030.74186486,
       107856.04281712, 108502.71948581, 106557.2401056 , 105659.59829843,
       105663.01875745, 107300.69453018, 106336.34733019, 107584.99034227,
       108089.2320392 , 106786.91702337]),
 np.array([106786.91702337, 104416.74000465, 101289.12525402, 101932.58219813,
       102625.04352578, 101767.46209616, 103345.4263012 , 102816.73322055,
       102417.59316407, 104439.37518975, 103755.22627215, 103817.9744686 ,
       107872.40234863, 108110.9662065 ]),
 np.array([108110.9662065 , 109544.86827069, 111072.22392645, 112618.46235766,
       113847.1768898 , 116708.86391903, 115790.02599715, 115614.72242411,
       119225.88436354, 121991.38468934, 123304.85972848, 125571.38040251,
       122456.3667249 ]),
 np.array([122456.3667249 , 127497.74699282, 128659.85495604, 125813.77115906,
       129008.46450085, 128111.00914756, 123039.92607546, 124723.87932757,
       124181.57385836, 125134.9276196 , 126027.8631434 , 129304.85119148,
       128912.58600657])]
```

Answer (score 2):

concatenate works.. I think you forgot some commas in your example data between each array in the list.

```
import numpy as np
a = [np.array([1,2,3]), np.array(['4','5','6'])]

np.concatenate(a)
```

outputs

```
array(['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
```