# How do I concatenate two arrays in this specific way

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I'm very new to python. I wondered how I can concatenate array a and b in this particular way.

I tried using stack, vstack, hstack, concatenate and a whole lot more, but I'm still not able to get my desired result.

```
a=  [[   0],
     [   1],
     [   2],
     [   3],
     [   4],
     [   5],
     [   6]]

b=  [[1,2,3],
     [1,2,3],
     [1,2,3],
     [1,2,3],
     [1,2,3],
     [1,2,3],
     [1,2,3]]

c = np.somefunction(a,b)


c = [
    [[0],[1,2,3]],
    [[1],[1,2,3]],
    [[2],[1,2,3]],
    [[3],[1,2,3]],
    [[4],[1,2,3]],
    [[5],[1,2,3]],
    [[6],[1,2,3]],
    ]
```

Comment: Shouldn't `c` start from  `[[0],[1,2,3]]`?

Comment: is `[0]` really an element in `a`? because that means the merge would throw it away

Comment: I edited the array

Comment: @DJosh well, now you don't need slicing, I edited my answer according to your edited question. cheers

Comment: Did you learn anything from all those things that you tried?  Most raise a mismatch shape error.  That's an important piece of information.  `hstack` runs but produces a (7,4) integer array.  But your desired `c` is what? (7,2)? but what dtype?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you have a **jagged array**. In other words, each sublist in your list of lists does not have the same length, so you cannot construct a regular NumPy `int` array.

Thus you can use a simple list comprehension or `map`. I assume that your `a` list of lists begins with `[0]` and ends with `[5]`:

```
c = [[i, j] for i, j in zip(a, b)]  # list comprehension
c = list(map(list, zip(a, b)))      # functional version

# [[[0], [1, 2, 3]],
#  [[1], [1, 2, 3]],
#  [[2], [1, 2, 3]],
#  [[3], [1, 2, 3]],
#  [[4], [1, 2, 3]],
#  [[5], [1, 2, 3]]]
```

Converting this to an array is possible, but it will have `object` dtype. For most purposes, it will have little benefit over a regular Python list of lists:

```
c_arr = np.array(c)

# array([[[0], [1, 2, 3]],
#        [[1], [1, 2, 3]],
#        [[2], [1, 2, 3]],
#        [[3], [1, 2, 3]],
#        [[4], [1, 2, 3]],
#        [[5], [1, 2, 3]]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Is there a speed difference if we use the way I am doing in my answer rather than using two variables?

Comment: @Bazingaa, Not sure. If there is, it's marginal. Complexity will be the same.

Comment: @That's a relief :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use list comprehensions. Using `concatenate` from NumPy won't work here because of the mismatch in the dimensions of the two arrays. Here I am assuming you want to start the array `a` from 1. If not, then you can simply replace `a[1:]` by `a`.

```
c = [list(i) for i in zip(a[1:],b)]

[[[1], [1, 2, 3]],
 [[2], [1, 2, 3]],
 [[3], [1, 2, 3]],
 [[4], [1, 2, 3]],
 [[5], [1, 2, 3]],
 [[6], [1, 2, 3]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

aaaand boom:

```
c = list(zip(a,b))
print([list(x) for x in c])
```

[pyFiddle](https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/5b13440e-b208-4b52-84f9-17318f6839de/?i=true)

Comment: Nope, this gives... `[([0], [1, 2, 3]),
 ([1], [1, 2, 3]),
 ([2], [1, 2, 3]),
 ([3], [1, 2, 3]),
 ([4], [1, 2, 3]),
 ([5], [1, 2, 3])]`

Comment: @jpp slicing it would do it, if the OP doesn't want zeroth index.

Comment: No, the problem is you have a list of tuples, see the parentheses in my previous comment.

Comment: @jpp Ah, Good catch, fixed!

Answer (score 0):

your arrays look like lists in which case the following may help

```
c=[list(i) for i in zip(a,b)]
```

else if they are numpy arrays, [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21887754/concatenate-two-numpy-arrays-vertically) may help you.

Comment: Nope, this gives... `[([0], [1, 2, 3]),
 ([1], [1, 2, 3]),
 ([2], [1, 2, 3]),
 ([3], [1, 2, 3]),
 ([4], [1, 2, 3]),
 ([5], [1, 2, 3])]`

Comment: That's not the issue. Notice the extra parentheses. Your code gives a list of tuples, which isn't what OP wants.

Comment: I've modified my solution as per the correct output format. Thanks for pointing out the tuples in my initial version.