# Combining four numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to combine 4 arrays into one in the following fashion

```
a = ([1,5,9])
b = ([2,6,10])
c = ([3,7,11])
d = ([4,8,12])

combination = [[1,2,3,4][5,6,7,8][9,10,11,12]]
```

any help would be greatly appreaciated

Comment: What was the problem when you tried to do this?

Comment: `np.stack((a,b,c,d)).T`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concatenate two NumPy arrays vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21887754/concatenate-two-numpy-arrays-vertically)

Comment: What's wrong with the obvious `np.array(combination)`?

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

a = ([1,5,9])
b = ([2,6,10])
c = ([3,7,11])
d = ([4,8,12])

print (np.stack((a,b,c,d), axis=-1))
```

Output:

```
[[ 1  2  3  4]
 [ 5  6  7  8]
 [ 9 10 11 12]]
```